# Could anyone please explain me this part of a code?

Tags: c++

I stumbled on this syntax while learning file handling.

```
while(fp.read((char*)&st,sizeof(student)) && found==0)
{
    if(strcmpi(st.retadmno(),n)==0)
    {
        st.show_student();
        cout<<"\nEnter The New Details of student"<<endl;
        st.modify_student();
        int pos=-1*sizeof(st);
        fp.seekp(pos,ios::cur);
        fp.write((char*)&st,sizeof(student));
        cout<<"\n\n\t Record Updated";
        found=1;
    }
}
```

Many articles only gave the generic syntax of this comparison but i couldn't find the actual meaning of it. THe syntax is followed by an if statement and is as follows.
Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear which part you are asking about. The `strcmpi`?

Comment: Don't use C-style casts. Use `static_cast` and if that doesn't compile, you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @NeilKirk Oh will try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
while(fp.read((char*)&st,sizeof(student)) && found==0)
```

reads a from the file, and if that is successful [1], checks that `found` is still zero, and enters the rest of the loop.

I personally would do:

```
while(!found && fp.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>&st, sizeof(student))
```

instead. That way, you don't read an extra student after writing.

[1] The sucess here is judged by the fact that `fp.read` returns the `istream` object that it operates on, and this can be converted to `void *` (pre-C++11) or `bool` (C++11 onwards) which reflects the status of `fp.good()`. In other words, the file is in a state where you can read more from it.

Comment: Oh. What does (char *) mean? Is it a typecast? So, does this means that the while part checks if the file contains any data?

Comment: It is indeed a "C-style cast", and has nothing to do with checking the content of the file. The `fp.read()` will set the `fail` bit of it can't read a full record, so then the `fp.read() && found == 0` will fail before checking `found`.

Comment: The purpose of the cast is simply to satisfy the arguments for `read`.

Comment: @matspeterson ohh okay